# ParentNode returns the false value

Tags: javascript, html

I have some troubles with ParentNode
See I'm Working on a WYSIWYG and I want to tell me what are the parents of selected text.
It works fine till I have two Texts with diffrent style
for example :

```
<b>Bold<b> NotBold
```

When I click on Bold it returns `BODY` tag and when I click on it again It retruns `B` tag.
and Same about `NotBold` When I click on `NotBold` after I clicked on `Bold` It returns `B` tag and when I click this again it returns me `BODY`
Where is the problem ?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",iFrameStart,false); //make iFrame Editable
function iFrameStart() {
    iframe.document.designMode="On";
}
let frame = document.getElementById('iframe');
frame.contentWindow.onselectstart=function()
{
    let frame = document.getElementById("iframe");
    let select=frame.contentWindow.getSelection(); //get the selected text
    let a = select.focusNode.parentNode; //get the parent of selected text
    //if it removed it returns the value in " "
    let array= ['ok']; //create an array
    while (a) {
        array.push(a); //add to the array
        a=a.parentNode;
    }
    console.log(array); //display the parents
};
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following. it is getting the parent node fine. You are not closing the  tag in your example

```
<iframe id='iframe'></iframe>


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", iFrameStart, false); //make iFrame Editable
function iFrameStart() {
  window.iframe.document.designMode = "On";
}
let frame = document.getElementById("iframe");
frame.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = "<b>Bold </b> <c>not bold</c>";
//window.iframe.document.getElementByTag("body")[0].innerHTML = "SAQIB";

frame.contentWindow.onclick = function() {
  let frame = document.getElementById("iframe");
  let select = frame.contentWindow.getSelection(); //get the selected text
  let a = select.focusNode.parentNode; //get the parent of selected text
  console.log(select.focusNode.parentNode);
  //if it removed it returns the value in " "
  let array = ["ok"]; //create an array
  while (a) {
    array.push(a); //add to the array
    a = a.parentNode;
  }
  console.log(array); //display the parents
};
```